# Regular expression giving incorrect output

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using regex to verify that a string only contains alphabets and spaces. Regex is defined as

```
var regex = /^[A-Za-z ]/;
```

but even if I am testing it with a string "X," , it is giving a true result.

What is the error here?

Comment: Your regex only means: *the string must start with a letter or a space*, but nothing else. Try this one: `/^[A-Za-z ]*$/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^[A-Za-z ]` only matches one character. and `^` means the start of the string. To accomplish what you want, use:

`+` - This means match one or more. Alternatively you can use:

`*` - Which means match zero or more.

But I think you're better off with the first one (`+`). Another thing is, match for the whole string. This means you have to search from the first to the last character.

`$` - This means match the end.

Your code should be like this:

```
var regex = /^[A-Za-z ]+$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches the first letter of your input and therefore true is returned.. You need to add `$` to make sure you only match a complete string from the beginning (`^`) to the end (`$`).

```
var regex = /^[A-Za-z ]*$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\ ]+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way:

```
/^[A-Za-z ]*$/
```

[Regex Demo](http://regexr.com?322h2)